# Add dashes to a date in Perl

Tags: perl, formatting

I need to be able to take a Perl string (a date in YYYYMMDD format) and add dashes (making it into YYYY-MM-DD) format. Is there an easy way to do this? Example, for January 1, 1900, I would have the input of 19000101 and need to make if 1900-01-01.

Comment: Hello @J.A., I noticed that you edited my answer yesterday and changed my numbers claiming to "correct" it, but it was already right apparently. Did you get a different result?

Comment: Yeah, but I realized what I did wrong :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
substr($date,$_,0) = '-' for (6,4);
```

Where `$date` is the date to change.

Answer (score 5):

Not particularly great in the sense that no validation is done on the date, but if you already know you're working with a valid date, this is both simple and fast:

```
$ perl -wle 'print join("-", unpack("A4A2A2", "19000101"))'
1900-01-01
```

Will work with any string---even non-dates---which is either a plus or a minus, depending on how you look at it:

```
$ perl -wle 'print join("-", unpack("A4A2A2", "YYYYMMDD"))'
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Answer (score 4):

Been a while since I played with perl but here's an alternative answer:

```
my $d = '19000101';
$d =~ s/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1-$2-$3/;
print $d;
```

will output:

```
1900-01-01
```

alternatively switch $1, $2, $3 around to format as you wish:

```
$d =~ s/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$3-$2-$1/;
```

will output:

```
01-01-1900
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a more general answer, you can look into using the [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) module.

```
# perl -MTime::Piece -E'my $time = Time::Piece->strptime("19000101", "%Y%m%d"); say $time->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");'
1900-01-01
```

Comment: This is my general preference - parsing a date then reformatting it gives more flexibility (and validation)